# How do I read and plot multiple .xvg files using python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have two .xvg files and I want to plot them in the same graph using python. The first column in each file is common -that means x axis will be common. I somehow was not able to arrange this common x axis. Since I am quite newcomer to coding, I would appreciate any help!

Here is my script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

resno, apo_rmsf, holo_rmsf = [], [], []

with open("RMSF_APO.xvg") as apofile:
    for line in apofile:
        apocols = line.split()

        if len(apocols) == 2:
            resno.append(float(cols[0]))
            apo_rmsf.append(float(cols[1]))

with open("RMSF_HOLO.xvg") as holofile:
    for line in holofile:
        holocols = line.split()

        if len(holocols) == 2:
            resno.append(float(cols[0]))
            holo_rmsf.append(float(cols[1]))


fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
#ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.set_title("APO-RMSF")    
ax1.set_xlabel('Residue Number')
ax1.set_ylabel('RMSF (nm)')
plt.plot(resno, apo_rmsf, c='r')
plt.plot(resno, holo_rmsf, c='b')
#ax1.plot(x,y, c='r', label='the data')
leg = ax1.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: can you provide us with the files if they are publicly available ?

Comment: Shouldn't these columns `cols[0]` be `apocols[0]` and `holocols[0]` ?